# Selectinput not updated when multiple =T

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I developed a small shiny app but I want it to display the variables of both datasets when I select them together with `multiple =T`. Any ideas?

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)

  bootstrapPage(
    selectInput('dataset', 'Choose data set', c('mtcars', 'iris'),multiple = T),
    selectInput('columns', 'Choose variable', "")
  )
```

**server.r**

```
function(input, output, session){

  # updates variable names based on selected dataset 
  outVar = reactive({
    names(get(input$dataset))
  })

  # create separate observeEvents to 
  observeEvent(input$dataset, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "columns", choices = outVar())
  })
}
```

Comment: Please check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46031333/4836511) and update the question accordingly, if it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass the selected inputs as a list to the `lapply` function and read the datasets in `input$dataset` iteratively for getting the `names()`

You could try the following:

```
  # updates variable names based on selected dataset 
  outVar = reactive({
    unlist(lapply(as.list(input$dataset), function(x){data <- get(x);names(data)}))
  })
```

---

Complete working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  selectInput('dataset', 'Choose data set', c('mtcars', 'iris'),multiple = T),
  selectInput('columns', 'Choose variable', "")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  # updates variable names based on selected dataset 
  outVar = reactive({
    unlist(lapply(as.list(input$dataset), function(x){data <- get(x);names(data)}))
  })

  # create separate observeEvents to 
  observeEvent(input$dataset, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "columns", choices = outVar())
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```